# How do I compare Two 2d arrays to see if their second element is matching?

Tags: python, arrays

So I have 2 2D arrays.

```
lefts = [[0,21],[0,23]]
rights = [[1,21],[1,23]]
```

I want to to check if lefts[0][1] matches any of rights[n number of times][1]. So in this case 0,21 will be first to check. Is 21 in any of rights[][1]. If yes then go to next 2nd element of lefts 0,23. At the end if both arrays matched it returns True, if there was still an element left hanging from either rights or lefts it would return False. So if rights had another array [1,22] this would return False.

My attempt I decided to just create 2 new list to append the second elements of the 2d array to.

```
check_lefts = []
check_rights = []
for i in range(len(left)):
    check_lefts.append(left[i][1])
for i in range(len(right)):
    check_rights.append(right[i][1])

if len(check_lefts) >= len(check_rights):
    for i in check_lefts:
        if i in check_rights:
            return True
        else:
            return False
elif len(check_lefts) < len(check_rights):
    for i in check_rights:
        if i in check_lefts:
            return True
        else:
            return False
```

Comment: Stack Overflow is not intended to replace existing documentation and tutorials.  Either look up standard looping and search examples, or work through a tutorial on `all` and `any`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If boths arrays are always the same length then try the following code:
For testing I added the prints.The code you have works, the only thing you have to change is that if they are not the same the loop breaks. If you want to return False make it a function. Once, again if the arrays are not equal you should change loop to iterate the length of the longest array.

```
     lefts = [[0,21],[0,23]]
     rights = [[1,21], [1,22]]


     for i in range(len(lefts)):
        if lefts[i][1] != rights[i][1]:
            print("False")
            break
        //delete the next lines    
        else:
            print("True")
```

Comment: Thanks I think it's working correctly. I just created another variable to sort the list and compare the sorted list.